# How to install new versions of js library with npm

Tags: npm, font-awesome, npm-install

When I run

> npm install font-awesome

version `4.7.0` is installed, but the current version is `5.11.2`.

New version contains new icons which I need in my project. When I run

> npm view font-awesome versions --json

I get

```
[
  "3.2.1",
  "4.0.3",
  "4.1.0",
  "4.2.0",
  "4.3.0",
  "4.4.0",
  "4.5.0",
  "4.6.1",
  "4.6.3",
  "4.7.0"
]
```

Can I somehow use new styles for this library and create npm package with appropriate version, so that everybody can use it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font Awesome version `5.x` has moved to a new package [location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free), namely the `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` package.

To install a version `5.x` of this package simply run:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then you should have the latest and greatest version `5.x` of the Font Awesome package. You can also install a specific version `5.x` release by issuing the following command: `npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@<version>`.

**Note**: According to their [documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome):

Now that Font Awesome 5 has been released we are marking version 4 as end-of-life. We **don't plan on releasing any further versions of the `4.x` or `3.x.`**

Hopefully that helps!